# Let handsontable treat numeric as numeric type

Tags: handsontable, angularjs-watch

I have a piece of code which stringifies a handsontable: [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/zopicu/3/edit?html,js,output). Changing a cell value in the handsontable will change its corresponding string.

```
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <script src="https://handsontable.github.io/ngHandsontable/node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://docs.handsontable.com/pro/1.8.2/bower_components/handsontable-pro/dist/handsontable.full.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://docs.handsontable.com/pro/1.8.2/bower_components/handsontable-pro/dist/handsontable.full.min.css">
    <script src="https://handsontable.github.io/ngHandsontable/dist/ngHandsontable.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <hot-table hot-id="mytable" datarows="db"></hot-table>
      <br><br>
      <span>{{ data }}</span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
function MainCtrl($scope, hotRegisterer) {
  $scope.db = [[5, 6], [7, 8]];

  $scope.$watch("db", function (newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log("$watch");
    var hot_instance = hotRegisterer.getInstance("mytable"); 
    $scope.data = hot_instance.getData();
  }, true)
}
MainCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'hotRegisterer'];

angular.module('app', ['ngHandsontable'])
  .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl)
```

However, if we put a new **numeric** value in the table, it will be considered as **string** in the array, which does not align with other value format of the array.

I don't know why handsontbale treats all cell values as string type by default. Is there a way of setting up such that new **numeric** cell value is treated as **numeric** type?

**Edit 1:** Following the answer of @acesmndr, I have done [this](https://jsbin.com/xuyaqal/1/edit?html,js,output). And I wanted to add a watcher to `db` to update `setting.columns` according to the number of the columns. However, I realise that if we set `settings.columns`, we could not add/remove columns any more by the contexte menu:

[image]

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must set the settings for the columns to be numeric. Here is  a working snapshot of your [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/tawusicura/2/edit?html,js,output)

Apparently setting the `type` and `invalidCellClassName` setting in the main setting object applies for the entire table allowing you to add or remove columns unlike the column level setting that I suggested prior to this edit which disabled adding or removing columns. Updated snapshot of your jsbin with setting for entire table is [here](https://jsbin.com/wasufecuka/edit?html,js,output)

```
 function MainCtrl($scope, hotRegisterer) {
  $scope.db = [[5, 6], [7, 8]];
  $scope.settings = {
    type:  'numeric',
    invalidCellClassName: 'someCssClass'
  };
  $scope.$watch("db", function (newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log("$watch");
    var hot_instance = hotRegisterer.getInstance("mytable"); 
    $scope.data = hot_instance.getData();
  }, true)
}
MainCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'hotRegisterer'];

angular.module('app', ['ngHandsontable'])
  .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl)
```

And add the settings to the `hot-table`

```
  <hot-table hot-id="mytable" datarows="db" settings="settings"></hot-table>
```

Comment: 1) I don't know the number of the columns, is there a way to set the whole table `type: 'numeric'`; 1) in this setting, i realise that when we enter a string `abc` in a cell, the background colour changes to red, how could I disable this? I don't want to raise any error or warning for strings.

Comment: You can add the `invalidCellClassName`  to define the css for the invalidated cell. So to disable this add a classname to it that doesn't exist `{type:'numeric',invalidCellClassName: 'someCssClass'}`. For setting it to the whole table I don't know if any easier way exists but you can always iterate over the length of the `$scope.db` array element to create an array of objects for the `$scope.settings.columns`

Comment: @Thomas So the only drawback of setting for each column is the column size is fixed. Check the edit to my answer! So setting the `type` and `invalidCellClassName` outside the column setting option applies for the entire table. I discovered this by hit and trial method though.